# How to pass parameters from one component to another, using ? and & operators in url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How to pass parameters from one component to another?
Currently I'm passing using **ActivatedRoute**.

In component1.ts

```
this.router.navigate(['/rate-list', 1]);
```

In app.module.ts

```
{ path: 'rate-list/:a', pathMatch: 'full', component: 
RateListComponent },
```

in component2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.parameter.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.parameter.a = params['a'];
  console.log(this.parameter.a);
});
}
```

this is working perfectly fine. This is creating url as **http://localhost:4200/rate-list/1** but I want to create **http://localhost:4200/rate-list?a=1**, this kind of url.
Is it possible to create such a url. If yes, then how?

Comment: See the difference between **MVC & Asp.Net** . Have you any idea about which one is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's achievable and for that, you need to use `NavigationExtras` in component1 as below:

```
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {
            a: 1               
        },
    };
    this.router.navigate(['./rate-list'], navigationExtras);
```

And in component2 make following changes:

```
public sub: Observable<string>;
public a : string;    
ngOnInit() {
            this.sub = this.route.queryParamMap
            .map((params) => params.get('a'));
            this.sub.subscribe((val) => this.a = val));
            console.log(this.a);
}
```

Lastly, you don't need to add any parameters to the routing ie:

```
{ path: 'rate-list', pathMatch: 'full', component: RateListComponent },
```

For more info read [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts

```
{ path: 'rate-list', pathMatch: 'full', component: RateListComponent }
```

in component2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.parameter.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.parameter.a = params.a;
        console.log(this.parameter.a);
    });
}
```

Look at https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/ for more details